# Dataweave Error for Null nodes

Tags: mule, mule-studio, mule-component, mule-el, dataweave

I have done coding in dataweava as

```
%dw 1.0
%input payload application/xml
%output application/xml skipNullOn="everywhere"
---
{((payload.*Order default []) map {
Order:{
    Channel:$.@EnterpriseCode,
    Code:$.@OrderNo,
    Status:$.@Status,
    OrderLines: {
    (($.OrderLines.*OrderLine default []) map {
    OrderLine:{
        EntryNumber:"abc",
        Status:$.@Status,

        (($.OrderStatuses.*OrderStatus default []) map {

        ShipDate:$.@StatusDate

        }) 
    }})}
}

}
)
}
```

But its giving error when assigning input as

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Order EnterpriseCode="111" OrderNo="222" Status="Scheduled">
    <OrderLines>
        <OrderLine PrimeLineNo="2" Status="Shipped" OrderedQty="1000">

        </OrderLine>
    </OrderLines>
</Order>
```

Any suggestions here? I have tried `default []` but its not working. When assigning `null node` its giving error. I have tried filter as `filter ($ != '')`

Comment: Please provide the example input and output data.

Comment: What error is it giving? Is it `Cannot coerce a :null to a :array (com.mulesoft.weave.mule.exception.WeaveExecutionException). Message payload is of type: LinkedList` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**XML input example**:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Order EnterpriseCode="111" OrderNo="222" Status="Scheduled">
  <OrderLines>
    <OrderLine PrimeLineNo="2" Status="Shipped" OrderedQty="1000">
       <OrderStatuses>
          <OrderStatus StatusDate="statusDate"></OrderStatus>
          <OrderStatus StatusDate="statusDate"></OrderStatus>
      </OrderStatuses>
    </OrderLine>
    <OrderLine PrimeLineNo="3" Status="Shipped3" OrderedQty="10003" ></OrderLine>
  </OrderLines>
</Order>
```

Note: In your example there are spaces between `OrderLine` open tag and close tag, you have to fix it:

```
<OrderLine PrimeLineNo="3" Status="Shipped3" OrderedQty="10003" ></OrderLine>
```

**Dataweave script**:

```
%input payload application/xml
%output application/xml skipNullOn="everywhere"
---
{
  ((payload.*Order default []) map {
    Order:{
      Channel:$.@EnterpriseCode,
      Code:$.@OrderNo,
      Status:$.@Status,

      OrderLines: {
        (($.OrderLines.*OrderLine default []) map {

          OrderLine:{
            EntryNumber:"abc",
            Status:$.@Status, 

            (($.OrderStatuses.*OrderStatus default []) map ((key,pos) -> {
                ShipDate:key.@StatusDate
            }) when $!='' otherwise {})

          }

        })
      }


    }
  })
}
```

You can't map a value if it doesn't exist, so you have to use "when/otherwise" to verify the existence of the elements.

Comment: Hi Davo, In tried this code, but it still giving error by providing this input `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Order EnterpriseCode="111" OrderNo="222" Status="Scheduled">
    <OrderLines>
     <OrderLine PrimeLineNo="2" Status="Shipped" OrderedQty="1000">
 </OrderLine>
   </OrderLines>
</Order>`

Comment: Ok, I built the script with an empty OrderLine like this: <OrderLine PrimeLineNo="3" Status="Shipped3" OrderedQty="10003" />  with the inline close tag.

Comment: Is there any other option for the input that I have provided?

Comment: Yeah Its working.. But again If anybody have different requirement it will change according to that. Thanks Davo

Comment: +1 for 'You can't map a value if it doesn't exist' , when you have a typo in the field names, this is the error  message you will get : `Cannot coerce a :null to ...`

Answer (score 0):

**Try this:**
This should solve your issue. (Unless not/otherwise) or (when/otherwise), any combination can be used as per your requirement. "Unless not" is recommended if ShipDate is present in most cases, else replace "unless not" with "when".

```
%dw 1.0
%input payload application/xml
%output application/xml skipNullOn="everywhere"
---
{
(
    (payload.*Order default []) map {
        Order: {
            Channel:$.@EnterpriseCode,
            Code:$.@OrderNo,
            Status:$.@Status,
            OrderLines: {
                (
                    ($.OrderLines.*OrderLine default []) map ({
                        OrderLine: {
                            EntryNumber:"abc",
                            Status:$.@Status,
                            (
                                ($.OrderStatuses.*OrderStatus) map {
                                    ShipDate:$.@StatusDate
                                }
                            )
                        }
                    }) unless not $.OrderLines.*OrderLine.OrderStatuses? otherwise {
                        OrderLine: {
                            EntryNumber:"abc",
                            Status:$.@Status                                
                        }
                    }
                )
            }
        }
    }
)
}
```

Comment: Hi J J, this code looks good as working for single iteration `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<Order EnterpriseCode="111" OrderNo="222" Status="Scheduled">


<OrderLine PrimeLineNo="2" Status="Shipped" OrderedQty="1000">

</OrderLine>

</OrderLines>
</Order>` But Is code fails for iterative elements of orderline

Comment: It fails for the input `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<Order EnterpriseCode="111" OrderNo="222" Status="Scheduled">

<OrderLines>

<OrderLine PrimeLineNo="1" Status="Released" OrderedQty="70">

<OrderStatuses>

<OrderStatus StatusDate="Shipped Date"/>

</OrderStatuses>

</OrderLine>

<OrderLine PrimeLineNo="2" Status="Shipped" OrderedQty="1000">

</OrderLine>

</OrderLines>
</Order>`

Answer (score 0):

Try following approaches:

- use "SkipNullOn" %output application/xml skipNullOn="everywhere"
- You can use when condition as shown below yourField: "null" when

`payload.yourField == null otherwise payload.yourField`

Answer (score 0):

Giving below the structure definition of Mule Message Object has 
Message
     Inbound Property
     Outbound Property
     Payload
Variable
     Flow Variable
     Session Variable
Attachment
Exception Payload

When a connector of a flow (listening on a port) receives the payload its called Inbound endpoint. 
When in a flow we have a connectore placed in the middle and send a payload its called Oubound endpoint. Here the all the outbound properties sent to the Http Outbound flow become Inbound Properties within that flow.

For detailed explanation see the link below.

https://docs.mulesoft.com/mule-user-guide/v/3.8/mule-message-structure.